# node.js socket.io room total of users

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to count the total number of users in a specific room and broadcast it to all the people in that room.

Here is what I have but I get an error:

```
var clients = io.sockets.clients(cc.lowerCase(data.roomname)).length;
         io.sockets.in(cc.lowerCase(data.roomname)).emit('updatetotal', { total: clients });
```

ERROR:

```
TypeError: Object #<Namespace> has no method 'clients'
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you show some more code this is not enough to debug the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since socket.io 1.0 its API was significantly changed so the old code might not work.

To get the number of clients in a room you can use this function:

```
var getUsersInRoomNumber = function(roomName, namespace) {
    if (!namespace) namespace = '/';
    var room = io.nsps[namespace].adapter.rooms[roomName];
    if (!room) return null;
    var num = 0;
    for (var i in room) num++;
    return num;
}
```

or more laconically:

```
var getUsersInRoomNumber = function(roomName, namespace) {
    if (!namespace) namespace = '/';
    var room = io.nsps[namespace].adapter.rooms[roomName];
    if (!room) return null;
    return Object.keys(room).length;
}
```

This function takes two agruments:

- `roomName`
- `namespace` (optional) default = `'/'`

To send message to users of this room only use `.to` method:

```
io.to(yourRoomName).emit('updatetotal', { total: getUsersInRoomNumber(yourRoomName) });
```

Comment: but the question is the number of users, not the number of sockets (sessions). If the same user have 3 or 4 browser tabs, this number of users will be 3 or 4... But real connected users only 1.

Answer (score 0):

to get total users in a room

```
io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(roomName).size
```