# io.sockets.clients(room).length not working in new socket.io version?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

io.sockets.clients(room).length was working fine in socket.io version 0.9.16 & 0.9.17 .

But seems to be its not working in socket.io version 1.0.4.

Getting an error  like "TypeError: Object # has no method 'clients'"

Can any one tell me what is the change need to work with new socket.io ?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24110046/2600208) might help

Answer (score 2):

From this previous question : [Listing all the clients connected to a room in Socket.io version > 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24153053/socket-io-list-all-the-clients-connected-to-a-room-in-version-1-0)

```
To get socket IDs of the clients connected to a room use this code:

var namespace = '/';
var roomName = 'my_room_name';
for (var socketId in io.nsps[namespace].adapter.rooms[roomName]) {
    console.log(socketId);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

io.sockets.clients(room).length function is almost not necessary at all
you can just use  javascript code to build a list of your clients

At the Server-side go ahead and create a new event

```
var users={};
socket.on('addUser',function(username){
socket.username=username;
users[username]=username;
io.sockets.emit('updateUsers',users);
});
```

then at the client-side javascript file emit the usernames

```
function addUser(){
socket.emit('addUser',prompt('What\'s your name'));
}
```

Comment: This doesn't account for disconnections :/

Comment: Do not provide incomplete answers because beginners like me would learn incomplete stuff.