# List rooms by total in rooms

Tags: node.js, socket.io

How would I go about returning a list of rooms depending on how many people are in each one?

I'm using socket.userID for each connection which I'm sure could be used to calculate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be done with the following two functions (the first one is taken from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108833/node-js-socket-io-room-total-of-users)):

```
var getRoomUserNum = function(roomName, namespace) {
    if (!namespace) namespace = '/';
    var room = io.nsps[namespace].adapter.rooms[roomName];
    if (!room) return null;
    return Object.keys(room).length;
}

var getRoomsSortedByUserNum = function(namespace) {
    if (!namespace) namespace = '/';
    var roomsUsersNum = {};
    var roomNames = [];
    for (var roomName in io.nsps[namespace].adapter.rooms) {
        roomsUsersNum[roomName] = getRoomUserNum(roomName, namespace);
        roomNames.push(roomName);
    }
    roomNames.sort(function(a, b) {
        return roomsUsersNum[a] < roomsUsersNum[b] ? 1 : -1;
    });
    return roomNames;
}
```

Then you just call `getRoomsSortedByUserNum();` optionally passing your namespace as an argument (which is `/` by default), and it returns an array of room names sorted by number of users in each one.

But keep in mind that when each socket is connected, [it's own room is automatically created](http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#default-room). So if you have 20 sockets and 3 manually created rooms, you actually have 23 rooms.